# Adding a new line to RichTextBox is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox control in my WPF application. I'm binding the Text for RichTextBox to a property. I'm trying add a new line to the text, but it is not working. I've tried to add "\n", "Environment.NewLine". None of these work.

This is what I have for the XAML:

```
  <RichTextBox Name="EmailBody" resources:HtmlRichTextBoxBehavior.Text="{Binding EmailBody}" IsDocumentEnabled="True" AcceptsTab="True"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"/>
```

And this is what I have for the Text Property:

```
 private string emailBody;

    public string EmailBody
    {
        get { return emailBody; }
        set
        {
            if (value != emailBody)
            {
                emailBody = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmailBody");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, in my ViewModel Class,I'm trying to add a new line to the Property:

```
EmailBody += Environment.NewLine;
```

This is the Behavior Class for the HtmlRichTextBoxBehavior:

```
      public class HtmlRichTextBoxBehavior : ObservableObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
   DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text", typeof(string),
   typeof(HtmlRichTextBoxBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnValueChanged));

        public static string GetText(RichTextBox o) { return (string)o.GetValue(TextProperty); }

        public static void SetText(RichTextBox o, string value) { o.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }

        private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
          DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var richTextBox = (RichTextBox)dependencyObject;
            var text = (e.NewValue ?? string.Empty).ToString();
            var xaml = HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml(text, true);
            var flowDocument = XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as FlowDocument;
            HyperlinksSubscriptions(flowDocument);
            richTextBox.Document = flowDocument;
        }

        private static void HyperlinksSubscriptions(FlowDocument flowDocument)
        {
            if (flowDocument == null) return;
            GetVisualChildren(flowDocument).OfType<Hyperlink>().ToList()
                     .ForEach(i => i.RequestNavigate += HyperlinkNavigate);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetVisualChildren(DependencyObject root)
        {
            foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(root).OfType<DependencyObject>())
            {
                yield return child;
                foreach (var descendants in GetVisualChildren(child)) yield return descendants;
            }
        }

        private static void HyperlinkNavigate(object sender,
         System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

This isn't working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I Would try appending a new line text to the end of the value that is being set to emailBody instead of trying to assign it to EmailBody.

You should be able to use the same method your trying to use

```
value += System.Environment.NewLine;
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this isn't working either.